# Show div only if mySQL info exists

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database storing some basic user info, so: name, email, and two phone numbers.  I want to make a page with dynamic php text showing the users info, but in the database only one phone number is required.  On the page I have:

```
<p id="first"> Some non-dynamic text </p>

<p> <?php echo $row_rsCustomer['first_name']; ?> </p>
<p> <?php echo $row_rsCustomer['email']; ?> </p>
<p> <?php echo $row_rsCustomer['phone_one']; ?> </p>
<p id="phonetwo"> <?php echo $row_rsCustomer['phone_two']; ?> </p>

<p id="second"> Some non-dynamic text </p>
```

I dont want the #second to be pushed down if the #phonetwo is empty.  I was thinking of using some javascript like this:

```
if( #phonetwo.innerhtml == ""){
    #phonetwo.style.display="none";
```

But I was wondering if there's a way to do this using php?  The javascript solution will work I suppose, but I'm pretty sure I've seen somewhere a more "correct" way to do this, I just don't remember what it was nor can I find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the paragraph in a conditional

```
<?php if(isset($row_rsCustomer['phone_two']) && $row_rsCustomer['phone_two']):?>
<p id="phonetwo"> <?php echo $row_rsCustomer['phone_two']; ?> </p>
<?php endif?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First check is it empty or not

```
<?php if(!empty($row_rsCustomer['phone_two'])) { ?>
<p id="phonetwo"> <?php echo $row_rsCustomer['phone_two']; ?> </p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You have a typo, change 'eumpty' to 'empty'.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (!empty($row_rsCustomer['phone_two'])) { ?>

<p id="phonetwo"><?php echo $row_rsCustomer['phone_two'] ?></p>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this pattern anytime you need to hide HTML from PHP:

```
<? if (your condition) { ?>
Html
<? } ?>
```

It is much better than doing it in JS since it does't send any data to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

check if `$row_rsCustomer['phone_two']` is not empty and then display your `<p>` :

```
<?php if (isset($row_rsCustomer['phone_two'])) { ?>
   <p id="phonetwo"><?php echo $row_rsCustomer['phone_two'] ?></p>
<?php } ?>
```